# AFNetworking alters JSON response?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2

I want to use AFNetworking for communicating to a RESTful webservice. I get a JSON response, but for some reason it is different from what the webservice sent.

My code:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
var contentTypes:NSMutableSet = manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableSet
contentTypes.addObject("text/html")
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes.copy() as NSSet
var parameters = ["format":"json"]
manager.GET( "http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php",
parameters: parameters,
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
             println("JSON: " + responseObject.description as String)
       },
failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })
```

The JSON should look like this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php?format=json

But for some reason println prints this:

```
{
data =     {
    "current_condition" =         (
                    {
            cloudcover = 16;
            humidity = 59;
            "observation_time" = "09:09 PM"; 
...
```

The : are replaced with =, [] with () and most of " are gone.

Does anybody know the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it isn't printing JSON, it's printing the object graph that was generated from the JSON (a combination of instances of `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, ...).

i.e. AFNetworking has already done a bunch of work for you to deserialise the data that was received.

Comment: How can I get the plain JSON?

Comment: Use `NSURLConnection` or change the `responseSerializer` to remove JSON - why do you want the JSON directly?

Comment: I do not realy need the JSON if there is a way to get the data from the response object. But I cannot find any way to do this.

Comment: `responseObject` will be an array or dictionary (depending on the JSON content) so you can access the contents using the provided API on those classes.